# Laravel show Class signature does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, rest, api, laravel-passport

Hi I got problem with my Laravel Rest-API apps, whenever i access localhost:8000/api/login in my Postman its say

> (1/1) ReflectionException Class signature does not exist

This is my artisan route:list for api/login

> POST     | api/login                               |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Api\UserController@login                       | api

This is my api route

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::post('oauth/token', '\Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController@issueToken');


Route::group(['namespace' => 'Api'], function () {
    Route::post('/login', 'UserController@login');
});
```

This is my UserController inside Api folder

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\User;
use Response;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->content = array();
    }

    public function login()
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])) {
            $user = Auth::user();
            $this->content['token'] =  $user->createToken('Pizza App')->accessToken;
            $status = 200;
        } else {
            $this->content['error'] = "Unauthorised";
             $status = 401;
        }

        return response()->json($this->content, $status);    
    }
}
```

please help me, if I trying to test my Rest-Api in postman, its keep saying

> (1/1) ReflectionException 
>   Class signature does not exist

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use a sample for custom authentication in laravel:
https://www.minddevelopmentanddesign.com/blog/add-custom-api-authentication-to-laravel/

Comment: i need solution why the laravel throw that error and what should I do.

Comment: Linking to some tutorial is not an answer. The link can become broken.